# Why is makeCoordinator() only called once?

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, arkit

The ARViewContainer has a coordinator, which is created once by `makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator`. A print("makeCoordinator()") in that method shows me, that it is only called once. It is the first print in the debug console. I also have a print("init") in the initializer of ARViewContainer, which is called many times according to the debug console.

Why is the ARViewContainer created many times (as expected, because the ContentView calls `ARViewContainer()` in its body), but the coordinator is only made once?

```
import ARKit
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    init(coordinator: Coordinator) {
        print("init")
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
        let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        config.planeDetection = [.horizontal, .vertical]
        config.environmentTexturing = .automatic
            
        if ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.supportsSceneReconstruction(.mesh){
            config.sceneReconstruction = .mesh
        }
    
    
        arView.session.run(config)
        arView.debugOptions = [
                .showWorldOrigin,
                .showSceneUnderstanding]
    
    
        arView.session.delegate = context.coordinator

        return arView
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        print("makeCoordinator()")
        return Coordinator()
    }
}
```

Comment: for consistency. There is no reason to call it again you can access it via `context.coordinator` if you need to make changes to it. `makeUIView` only gets called once too. The rest is done in the `update` method. It is here things like delegates should be you don't want them recreated all the time because you would miss notifications or calls in between.

Comment: I added makeUIView to the code above. My goal is not to call it again, my goal is to understand why it isn't called again. I just don't understand it.

Comment: because SwiftUI only calls it once right before the `make` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiviewcontrollerrepresentable/makecoordinator()-32trb nobody here is privy to the inner workings but that is what the documentation says.